# How to avoid circular dependency with Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have the following Module :

```
@Module
class HomeModule(private val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    fun provideContext() = context

    @Provides
    fun provideHomeUi(): HomeUi {
        return HomeUi()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHomePresenter(homeUi: HomeUi): HomePresenter {
        return HomePresenter(homeUi)
    }
}
```

Those injected fields in `HomeUi.kt`

```
@Inject lateinit var context: Context
@Inject lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter
```

And this one in `HomePresenter.kt`

```
@Inject lateinit var context: Context
```

Here my Deps Component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        NetworkModule::class,
        HomeModule::class
))
interface Deps {
    fun inject(homePresenter: HomePresenter)
    fun inject(homeActivity: HomeActivity)
    fun inject(homeUi: HomeUi)
}
```

I am using Dagger 2.10 but a `StackOverflowError` is thrown. I am looking for a way to avoid my circular dependency.

Note : This is my HomeUi which is infinitely instantiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you'd be calling field injection on `HomeUi` from within your presenters constructor, thus triggering an infinite loop since neither object can finish being constructed without the other (?). This looks like a really bad approach and you should try to move your dependencies into the objects constructors instead of creating half-finished objects.

Use field injection primarily for objects that you can't create yourself, e.g. with Android framework types. IMHO `inject(homeActivity: HomeActivity)` should be the only method of your component.

Cyclic dependencies are hard to manage and there is no perfect solution, but you can try things like switching to `Provider<HomePresenter>` to delay the dependency and be able to resolve it this way.

The following should do what you intended, and please note how I'm using constructor injection instead of having 2 additional methods in the module.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
    NetworkModule::class,
    HomeModule::class
))
interface Deps {
  fun inject(homeActivity: HomeActivity)
}

@Module
class HomeModule(private val context: Context) {

  @Provides
  fun provideContext() = context

}

@Singleton
class HomeUi @Inject constructor(presenter : Provider<HomePresenter>, context : Context)
{
  // use with presenter.get()
}

@Singleton
class HomePresenter @Inject constructor(homeUi : HomeUi)
```

Please note that using a `Provider<T>` is the cheapest way to resolve a cyclic dependency that I know of, but it might not be suited for every situation.

Comment: I have followed your approach by using inject() only for objects that I can't create and it looks better indeed. Thanks for your advices !